# printing arguments from the following func(int *argc, char ***argv)

Tags: c++

I have a function declared this way:

```
void func( int *argc, char ***argv )
{
        printf("argc= %d\n",*argc);
        printf("argv 0 = %s\n",*argv[0]); // correct printout
        printf("argv 1 = %s\n",*argv[1]); // segmentation fault


}
```

It is called from the main program:

```
        func(&argc, &argv);
```

when I execute it with one argument, as I would like to, I get Segmentation fault. Why? If there is no argument and the "segmentation fault" line is commented, there is no error and name of the executable is printed out.

Comment: what arguments do you pass exactly? You should not read from `argv` without taking into account `argc`

Answer (score 2):

that's a problem of [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence):
subcript (`a[]`) has a higher precedence than dereference (`*a`).

so `*argv[1]` is really `*(argv[1])`.
however your `argv` does not point to an array (just to a location of the original `char**` pointer), so `argv[1]` does not hold a valid address and dereferencing it yields to a segfault.

this should do the trick:

```
void func( int *argc, char ***argv )
{
        int i;
        printf("argc= %d\n",*argc);
        printf("argv 0 = %s\n",(*argv)[0]); // correct printout
        for(i=1; i<*argc; i++) {
            printf("argv %d = %s\n", i, (*argv)[i]);
        }
}
```

(although for all practical purposes i would always assume that arguments passed to a program (as in `main(int, char**)`) should be considered `const`, in which case you would gain little by the extra indirection)

Comment: if this solves your problem, you should *accept* the answer, so it doesn't show up as "needs attention".